# Smart way to concat two Sets

Tags: c#-4.0

Say I have two sets

```
var Set1 = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
var Set2 = new[] { "1", "2", "3" };
```

To concat these two sets usually i do

```
foreach (string itm1 in Set1 )
{
     foreach (string itm2 in Set2)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(itm1 + itm2);
     }
}
```

Is there any LINQ style of getting the same result?

Comment: Linq's ZIP can help here

Answer (score 2):

```
var strs = Set1.SelectMany(s1 => Set2.Select(s2 => s1 + s2))
foreach(string s in strs)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

alternatively using the query syntax:

```
var strs = from s1 in Set1
           from s2 in Set2
           select s1 + s2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 var concatSet =Set1
                .SelectMany(
                             item => Set2,
                             (i1, i2) => (i1 + i2)
                           );
```